# I am not able to write the script. How to download a excel file in chorme browser using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Here is my site url-`117.247.65.9/vms_test`. Login Username-thane, Password-12345. 1)Login into system, 2) click into Data Management module, 3) click into Download data entry template. I am not able to write the script for download. Here is my code-

```
public class DownloadUpload {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, AWTException {


    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Arijit Mohanty\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver fd = new ChromeDriver();

    fd.get("http://117.247.65.9/vms_test");
    fd.manage().window().maximize();
    fd.findElement(By.id("j_username")).sendKeys("thane");
    fd.findElement(By.id("j_password")).sendKeys("12345");
    fd.findElement(By.id("log")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    WebElement e1 = fd.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Data Management')]"));
    Actions act = new Actions(fd);
    act.moveToElement(e1).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(5000);


    fd.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains=(.,'downloadDataEntry')]")).click();



}

}
```

after execute the script an error message is occur. I am not able to run the script in Google Chrome browser. Please help me. how to write the script for download data entry excel.

Comment: In which step are you exactly stuck? Paste the error/stacktrace and update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Updated and checked below code, it is working fine. And also, it would be better if you avoid using hard wait(thread.sleep), use explicit or fluent waits.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Arijit Mohanty\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver fd = new ChromeDriver();

fd.get("http://117.247.65.9/vms_test");
fd.manage().window().maximize();
fd.findElement(By.id("j_username")).sendKeys("thane");
fd.findElement(By.id("j_password")).sendKeys("12345");
fd.findElement(By.id("log")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
WebElement e1 = fd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='menu']/ul/li[2]/a"));
Actions act = new Actions(fd);
act.moveToElement(e1).clickAndHold().build().perform();
fd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*@id='menu']/ul/li[2]/ul/li[1]/a")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Please update me if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Corrections to your code:

1. Don't use hard wait(i.e Thread.sleep())
2. Xpath that you have provided for the download data entry was wrong.

Below is the code:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class DownloadUpload { public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, AWTException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Arijit Mohanty\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver fd = new ChromeDriver();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(fd,15);

    fd.get("http://117.247.65.9/vms_test");
    fd.manage().window().maximize();
    fd.findElement(By.id("j_username")).sendKeys("thane");
    fd.findElement(By.id("j_password")).sendKeys("12345");
    fd.findElement(By.id("log")).click();

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Data Management")));
    WebElement e1 = fd.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Data Management')]"));

    Actions act = new Actions(fd);
    act.moveToElement(e1).build().perform();


    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Download Data Entry Template')]")));
    fd.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Download Data Entry Template')]")).click();
}
}
```

Try it and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and your guidance @Akarsh. Now your updated code working correctly. Thanks a lot...